# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'. firebase snapshot

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'. firebase snapshot

```
void activateListeners() {
    locationStream =
        database
            .child('uid')
            .onValue.listen((event) {
          final data  = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
          //final liveLocation = LiveLocation.fromRTDB(data);
        final longitude = data['longitude'] as double;
          final latitude = data['latitude'] as double;
          setState(() {
            displayText = 
              'lat: ${longitude.toStringAsFixed(2)} and lng: ${latitude.toStringAsFixed(2)}';

          });
        });
  }
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly ?

Comment: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.